# Will this pulley modification result in more torque on my stepper motor

Tags: torque, stepper-motor

I have a Nema23 that has a 1.8 degree stepping resolution. The motor has a GT2 pulley attached on the rotating element. This GT2 pulley is coupled with another pulley, using a belt, which is directly around the shaft of a lead screw.

I'd like to increase my stepping resolution, I already use micro-stepping, so I was thinking of using a 60 tooth pulley on my lead screw and a 20 tooth pulley on the stepper.  Such that a step from my motor would result in less rotation of the lead screw.  But what I am curious about is how will this affect the torque experienced by the motor?  Will I be able to lift the same load, or maybe even more?  Are there any drawbacks to such a modification?

Comment: PS- you may know this, but can't hurt mentioning - while you can readily get a 32x-128x microstepping driver now, and it will help extend the range of speed, as well improve smoothness at low speed, by creating a good sine-wave voltage or current profile, it probably won't give you nearly that multiple of an improvement in the position resolution and esp. accuracy when standing still. That's the driver. Wrt/ the belt, drawback is complexity, including however you plan on controlling belt tension.

Comment: you don't tell us the current sizing of the pulleys so it's hard to say how this will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you're right. Your stepper motor will produce 3 times more torque, 3 times more resolution.

And 3 times slower angular speed on the lead screw.

Comment: After reading this again I am a little confused.  Are you saying that the stepper motor rotating at a fixed speed (frequency A) will now experience 3x less torque when doing a task with this 3:1 gear ratio versus before?  Or are you saying the opposite?

Comment: it will experience less torque. the smaller the power wheel the smaller torque it feels. but the other pulley will turn slower.